# xargs and terraform state rm

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

```
✗  terraform state list | grep kubernetes_namespace | xargs -0 -n1 echo                 
module.prod_eks_cluster.kubernetes_namespace.namespace["ci"]
module.prod_eks_cluster.kubernetes_namespace.namespace["grafana"]
module.prod_eks_cluster.kubernetes_namespace.namespace["prod"]
module.prod_eks_cluster.kubernetes_namespace.namespace["prometheus"]
module.staging_eks_cluster.kubernetes_namespace.namespace["ci"]
module.staging_eks_cluster.kubernetes_namespace.namespace["grafana"]
module.staging_eks_cluster.kubernetes_namespace.namespace["prometheus"]
module.staging_eks_cluster.kubernetes_namespace.namespace["staging"]

✗  terraform state list | grep kubernetes_namespace | xargs -0 -n1 terraform state rm
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
╷
│ Error: Invalid character
│ 
│   on  line 2:
│   (source code not available)
│ 
│ Expected an attribute access or an index operator.
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `-0` it with `-d'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

[konsolebox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445221/konsolebox) is right, replacing -0 with -d'\n' works.

As Martin explained here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24990#issuecomment-649890051

> If you are using a Unix-based system, like Linux or Mac OS X, you can put the address in single quotes ' to ensure that the shell will not parse the address before Terraform does:

```
terraform state rm 'module.p1-abc.module.loadbalancer.azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend_pool["vm"]'
```

> If you're using the Windows Command Prompt, the convention on Windows
> is to escape the quotes using backslashes, like this:

```
terraform state rm module.p1-abc.module.loadbalancer.azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend_pool[\"vm\"]
```

To summarize, if you use linux or macOS, to delete the list of resources from your example, you can run:

```
  terraform state list | grep kubernetes_namespace | xargs -d'\n' -n1 terraform state rm
```